# Getting TypeError with pywinauto when calling application.start for Store Apps

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I tried to automate an application installed from the Microsoft Store, tried different applications, but I allways got the same error.
I used this code:

```
import subprocess
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

app = Application(backend='uia').start(subprocess.call(r"start shell:appsFolder\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm!App", shell=True))
```

The programm opens as expected, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\auto.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = Application(backend='uia').start(subprocess.call(r"start shell:appsFolder\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm!App", shell=True))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1018, in start
    if '.exe' in cmd_line and self.backend.name == 'win32':
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong usage. `subprocess.call` already starts the process and returns integer exit code. So you're passing integer instead of string command to method `start`.

But `start` command is not an executable, so pywinauto with default params is not able to run it. You need explicit usage of `cmd.exe` and connect to the child process of `cmd.exe`:

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"cmd.exe /c start shell:appsFolder\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_cv1g1gvanyjgm!App", create_new_console=True, wait_for_idle=False)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re=".*WhatsApp.*")
```

or use `subprocess.call` and then connect by title.