# How to use Desktop object to connect to app with changing window titles

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am new to pywinauto but I have read all the documentation. I am trying to automate the Spotify app on Windows (i.e. the Microsoft Store option). I am using UIA backend. The only problem I am having is that because pywinauto's Desktop object is looking for a specific window title, it doesn't allow me to automate as Spotify's window title can change depending on what song is being played at any given moment (and there's no word "Spotify" in the window title).

I experimented with trying to obtain the process ID, but it doesn't seem to find the exe name (Spotify.exe) or doesn't work with the Desktop object, which I need to be able to access child_window, etc. My code is below.

Can someone assist with advising how to go about making the Desktop object work when the app's window title is not constant and can't be used to identify the app, and since it's a Microsoft Store app, it spawns multiple processes so using just the Application object is not an option either.

```
import pywinauto
import subprocess
from pywinauto import Desktop, application
from pywinauto.application import Application

sp = subprocess.call("start shell:AppsFolder\SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_zpdnekdrzrea0!Spotify",shell=True)
app = pywinauto.Application(backend='uia').connect(path="Spotify.exe")

#this works only if there is NO song playing on Spotify; if any song is playing, 
#it fails to work since it can't find any app window with the title "Spotify"
#and the name of the window is instead the current song playing
#which I don't know what it is going to be at any given point
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").Spotify
#does not work
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").window(process=app.process)

dlg.child_window(title="Your Library", control_type="Hyperlink",found_index=0).wait("exists",30).invoke()

dlg.child_window(title="Orchestra", control_type="Hyperlink",found_index=0).wait("exists",30).invoke()
try:
    dlg.child_window(title="Play Orchestra", control_type="Button").wait("exists",5).invoke()
except:
    pass

    # this also doesn't work most of the time
    dlg.wait("",10).close()
```

Comment: So does this line `app = pywinauto.Application(backend='uia').connect(path="Spotify.exe")
` not work?

Comment: It doesn't seem I can make use of app to call child_window, it only works with Desktop object. So calling the app to connect to Spotify may work, but no way to use it beyond that since I need the Desktop object to make use of the child_window function

Comment: Could you use the method for starting the application mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247297/getting-typeerror-with-pywinauto-when-calling-application-start-for-store-apps)? Eg. `app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_zpdnekdrzrea0!Spotify", create_new_console=True, wait_for_idle=False)`

Comment: Yes, it seems to work when Spotify is not running in conjunction with using `dlg = app.top_window()` that you had suggested, but it doesn't work anymore if the Spotify app was already open like did before when we used subprocess.call. I tried using
`pid = application.process_from_module(module = 'Spotify.exe') 
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(process = pid)` but that didn't work for calling the `dlg = app.top_window()` either when the app is already running. (Error is still `RuntimeError("No windows for that process could be found")`)

Comment: Do you find anything identifiable with `Inspect.exe` or another inspection tool? [docs link](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#gui-objects-inspection-spy-tools)

Comment: Yes I tried that, but sadly no, because Spotify runs in a Chrome wrapper, no unique identifying elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249891/discussion-between-dash-and-brian).

Answer (score 1):

From the How To's page in the docs [How to specify a dialog of the application](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html#how-to-specify-a-dialog-of-the-application), you should be able to use the `top_window()` method to get the window with the highest Z-Order (although the docs say that it's

> fairly untested ... It will definitely be a top level window of the application - it just might not be the one highest in the Z-Order.

However if there's only one window in the app that shouldn't be an issue.

```py
dlg = app.top_window()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that doesn't work either:

    dlg = app.top_window()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1156, in top_window
    raise RuntimeError("No windows for that process could be found")
RuntimeError: No windows for that process could be found